# Terragrunt auto apply

Tags: terraform, terragrunt

I am trying to run terragrunt with auto-apply for that I've used cli flag `--terragrunt-working-dir`

From the documentation

> When passed in, don’t show interactive user prompts. This will default
>   the answer for all prompts to ‘yes’

The command which I tried is

```
terragrunt apply --terragrunt-non-interactive --terragrunt-working-dir <dir>
```

But it still asks for me the prompt

> terragrunt version v0.23.2

Comment: What prompt do you get?

Comment: Its terraform prompt  to receive `yes`

Comment: It would help if you could share the terragrunt command including the output up until the point of the prompt.

Answer (score 15):

Terragrunt is a thin wrapper around terraform, so command-line flags you send that aren't Terragrunt specific will go to the terraform command.

You need to add the [terraform apply command-line flag `-auto-approve`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/apply.html#auto-approve) to have it skip the "yes" prompt:

```
terragrunt [your other flags] -auto-approve
```

Answer (score 3):

These are the two ways to skip the prompt and do same as terraform apply -auto-approve

For anyone who still wants auto approve with apply-all. I got a workarounds by using bash hack

```
echo "Y" | terragrunt apply-all
```

If you want to skip terragrunt's prompts, then use:

```
terragrunt run-all apply --terragrunt-non-interactive
```

Comment: --terragrunt-non-interactive makes the trick . Thanks

Answer (score 1):

With terraform v0.14.10 and terragrunt v0.28.21 you can use:

```
terragrunt apply/destroy -auto-approve --terragrunt-working-dir <dir>
```