Auto approve apply external dependency for all Terragrunt modules
When I run terragrunt run-all plan I get prompted to approve an external dependency for each module I have.
How can I auto approve it for all modules?
Module:          /Users/mugen/tf/environments/dev/module1
External dependency:     /Users/mugen/tf/environments/global/iam
Should Terragrunt apply the external dependency? (y/n) y
...
Module:          /Users/mugen/tf/environments/dev/modulen
External dependency:     /Users/mugen/tf/environments/global/iam
Should Terragrunt apply the external dependency? (y/n) y


This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62429042/terragrunt-auto-apply

Did you try --terragrunt-include-external-dependencies flag?

You should add the flag --terragrunt-include-external-dependencies to the plan command:
terragrunt run-all plan --terragrunt-include-external-dependencies
